# A question on definition of the Tangent space

Tags: soft-question, differential-geometry

In the definition of the Tangent space under [definition via derivations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space)

> Pick a point $x$ in $M$. A derivation at $x$ is a linear map $D : C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R} $ which has the property that for all $ƒ, g$ in $C^{\infty}(M)$:
>
>    $D(fg) = D(f)\cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot D(g)$
>
> modeled on the product rule of calculus. These derivations form a real vector space in a natural manner; this is the tangent space $T_xM$

My question is, it is given that $D : C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ is real valued and gives out scalar and how does  $D(fg)$ forms a vector space ?

Same is the case in the next sentence as well.

Comment: Just to add that derivations are used when the manifold is not embedded in some ambient $\mathbb{R^n}$, since the tangent space as a tangent vector space only makes sense for embedded manifolds.

Comment: Please ignore my previous; I did not read carefully-enough, and the edit function seems disabled. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent space $T_xM$ is the collection of all linear mappings $D:C^\infty(M)\to\mathbb R$ (not the scalars $D(fg)$ )that satisfy the property
$$D(fg) = D(f)\cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot D(g), \forall f,g\in C^\infty(M).$$ 
These mappings form a vector subspace of the space of all linear functionals on $C^\infty(M)$ (which is itself a vector space): for any two of such linear mappings $D_1$ and $D_2$ and any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, $D:=aD_1+bD_2$ is another linear mapping that satisfies the property. It's quite straightforward to check
\begin{eqnarray}
D(fg)&=&aD_1(fg)+bD_2(fg)\\
&=&a[(D_1f)g+f(D_1g)]+b[(D_2f)g+f(D_2g)]=(Df)g+f(Dg).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: could you please explain how ?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you. I was'nt aware of notion of vector space for linear functionals.

Comment: what kind of a vector space is $C^\infty(M)$ ?

Comment: please ignore my last question.